# sql statement "for each state with more than 20 members whose first name start with “D”."?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to

> List the total amount of credit limit for each state with more than 20
>       members whose first name start with “D”. (Use `Members` Table).

Here's what I have so far, but it gives and error, so i'm not sure how to make it only include states with 20+ D first names.

```
SELECT State, SUM(CreditLimit) AS TotalCreditLimit
FROM MEMBERS
WHERE First Like ‘D%’ AND COUNT(*) > 20
Group By State
```

Comment: What error do you get? (I bet it has to do with the funky quotes)

Comment: ^the quotes were normal, just looked weird when i transferred it over i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your quotes and move the `count` to a `having` like this:

```
SELECT State, SUM(CreditLimit) AS TotalCreditLimit
FROM MEMBERS
WHERE First Like 'D%'
Group By State 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the HAVING clause to filter groups out

```
SELECT State, SUM(CreditLimit) AS TotalCreditLimit
FROM MEMBERS
WHERE First Like 'D%'
Group By State 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 20
```